# Exception is caught when Exception is not thrown

Tags: java, exception, findbugs

I have the following code and findbugs complains that "`Exception is caught when Exception is not thrown`" under dodgy code. I do not understand how to solve this. `getPMMLExportable` throws a `MLPMMLExportException`.

```
public String exportAsPMML(MLModel model) throws MLPmmlExportException {
    Externalizable extModel = model.getModel();

    PMMLExportable pmmlExportableModel = null;

    try {
        pmmlExportableModel = ((PMMLModelContainer) extModel).getPMMLExportable();
    } catch (MLPmmlExportException e) {
       throw new MLPmmlExportException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the point of catching the exception? You just throw it again. Just remove the try/catch.

Comment: I added it in case I am going to log a message before the exception is thrown

Comment: then you should use "throw e"

Comment: Don't catch-and-throw. This is a well-known code smell, or should I say anti-pattern.

Answer (score 14):

This is a very famous findbug warning,

according to official documentation this kind of warning is generated when

- Method uses a try-catch block that catches Exception objects, but Exception is not thrown within the try block.
- Sometimes it also is thrown when we use `catch(Exception e)` to catch all types of exceptions at once, it could mask actual programming problems, so findbugs asks you to catch specific exception, so that run-time exceptions can be thrown which indicate programming problems.

for more understanding(and the solution as well) you can have look at the [official documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION).

for your case it seems that statements in `try` clause do not throw the exception you are handling in `catch` clause

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to catch all exceptions, and want to avoid this issue, you need to break your catching into at least 2 blocks. An easy way to do this is catch runtime exceptions in one block, and all others in another.

[Discussed here as well](https://github.com/Alluxio/alluxio/issues/10459)

```
try {
  // Do stuff here, like process json, which might throw a json processing error
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't process stuff", e);
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Something failed!", e);
}
```